# Did my home's builder not properly protect the outside molding from water?

Tags: windows, trim, flashing

Ok so for a few months now I've noticed that the outside moldings of the garage doors and the windows are beginning to look really bad. The wood looks like it's warping and rotting I guess because of water that is getting inside...?

Is this shoddy work on the builder's part? This home is less than 9 years old. Or it this normal for these decorative outdoor molding around windows to decay like that?

I asked my neighbor and he apparently had to pay someone to fix that and he had to replace some of the frame around the garage doors. He said something about the flashing being done improperly.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: photo 1]
[image: photo 2]
[image: photo 3]
[image: photo 4]

How do I determine how bad is the damage here, and what's the proper way to fix this?

Comment: Does it feel mushy? Or is it just the paint that is badly peeling?

Comment: Not mushy, at least not the windows I was able to inspect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there should be flashing but that isn't the main issue.

This is the architect's problem.  The top of your molding is flat.  Where do you think water will go on a flat surface?  It will sit on it.  It will then seep into the wood and to the wood underneath it, slowly water logging and rotting all of it.  If someone showed me your new molding I would imagine this in 3-4 years.   You are lucky for it to last that long.

You need to replace the wood.  Then add flashing but more importantly add a triangular piece to the top that slopes out.  If all of the water slopes off of this at the top and you paint it every 5-8 years you will be fine.

Comment: Sorry I could've swore I marked this years ago as the answer! Better late than never I guess...

Answer (score 1):

In that third photo, it doesn't look like there's any flashing at all!

Whenever there's an opening in an exterior wall, there should be flashing at the top that runs from inside the siding to cover the top surfaces of the trim around the opening.

Comment: And the surface is warped **concave** to hold a puddle of water...  And draw water over the front edge and back to soak the underside trim...

Comment: @User58220 - note that this was flat before the water sitting on it for years.